# Is there any way to hide my real version of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to hide my real version of Google Chrome on Windows and  make remote server indetify my browser as mobile browser on android and my OS as Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you are looking for is the changing of your 'User Agent'.

**Change User Agent**

1. To do this in Chrome you need to first open up your developer tools. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Click the three vertical dots in the top right of the DevTools window.
3. Go to More Tools -> Network conditions.
4. You can change your user agent from the drop down.
5. Refresh the page.

**Changing Resolution**

1. In Chrome you need to first open up your developer tools. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)
2. At the top of the web page there would be a drop down where you can select what device you want the browser to run as.